# What effect has the unit size in Rome 2 Multiplayer Campaign?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

If I host a multiplayer campaign (coop or head to head), I can set the "Unit size" (Small - Ultra). What does this mean? Is it only a visual effect? Does this have any impact on the gameplay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is only a visual/graphics settings. Your units will still have the same number of people in them a far as the battle simulation is concerned, but less will be drawn.